# Is this guy a Star Wars character?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification

I got this guy for 50 cents at my local comic store. He was in the "fodder bin", probably due to missing one hand and all accessories. My guess is that he is a Star Wars character (a Sith), but I'm not completely up to date with the franchise.

Maybe he is one of many versions of a Darth Sidious toy figure, and without accessories is more difficult to identify.

[image]

Is this guy a known Star Wars character?

Comment: That looks more *God of War* than *Star Wars* to me.

Comment: Is there any writing on the back or the feet?

Comment: Star Wars action figures almost always have their toes pointing out, and this guy does not.

Comment: Or maybe *Mad Max*

Comment: First hit on Google Reverse Image search was "2017 Times person of the year". Something got broke in translation clearly.

Comment: @Valorum, thanks! I forgot to include that. Feet have peg holes, but on the back says "Hasbro China 2008 LFL C-001C"

Comment: @Buzz, I don't own any Star Wars figures. I know that there are different versions, with different sizes, articulation, etc. The articulation in this figure looks similar to other Star Wars figures that I have seen, that's why my first guess was "Star Wars". Thus said, it could belong to a completely different franchise. It still a little bit soon, but if it hasn't been identified already, maybe it is _not_ a Star Wars character.

Comment: Well, LFL Is [LucasFilm Limited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucasfilm#Filmography);  but that particular code doesn't come up as the figure in the picture - https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/star-wars-rancor-hasbro-china-2008-542085700

Comment: [Alive and well!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7677/3823)

Comment: The missing hand certainly seems to imply _Star Wars_.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Without having one to compare in person, and going by the photo you've provided, I believe this is [the Palpatine figure from the Dark Empire 2 line released in 2008](http://jedibusiness.com/figureDetails.aspx?id=97), except missing his cloak and saber.

[image: palpatine figure from 2008. check out the foot.]

[image: image added by richard]

The hair color and expression of the face are a match, and if you look at the exposed foot in the photo, it looks like he has a similar wrapping around his foot. Additionally, the figure was released in 2008, matching the production date on the figure. LFL C-001C is also a production code for Star Wars figures.

Comment: That looks like a dead ringer to me. Zoom in on the Palpatine pic and you can see the wrapping on the foot. You can also see wrapping on the hands. And the heads look identical. Good job on that pic find.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a better pic and a video review of the toy.

Comment: In light of the latest image, I don't think you need to qualify "I believe" anymore.